# Why does my Django registration form is not rendered?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have default Django registration form. It is sent to render to the page based on type of request and user login status. This logic is implemented in `views.py` file. Somehow, if user is not logged in and `GET` request is sent to the page, my view returns `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'form' is referenced before assignment`. How could this happen?
P.S. Here's my view.

```
def EmplRegisterView(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        group = Group.objects.get(name = 'Employers')
        user.groups.add(group)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('ProfileSetup')
else:
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        logout(request)
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
context = {
    'form':form,
}

return render(request, "registerPage.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
def EmplRegisterView(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name = 'Employers')
            user.groups.add(group)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('ProfileSetup')

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        logout(request)
        
    context = {
    'form':form,
    }

    return render(request, "registerPage.html", context)
```